# SQLite SELECT with JOIN needs to return row only if every row in second table is true for WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, where-clause, exists

**I need the select to be empty even if only one row in the second table doesn't meet the dates condition.** But each parking space has multiple reservations in Reservations table and even if one of the reservation meets the criteria of not being in the range I will get the ID of parking space.

My SELECT

```
SELECT Parking_Spaces.ID_Parking_Space FROM Reservations 

INNER JOIN Parking_Spaces ON Reservations.ID_Parking_space = Parking_Spaces.ID_Parking_Space
AND (Reservations.Arrival_time NOT BETWEEN "2000-12-15" AND "2005-12-15")
AND (Reservations.Departure_time NOT BETWEEN "2000-12-15" AND "2005-12-15")
```

Table example: I don't want to SELECT ID_Parking_Space from this table, because first row doesn't meet my condition. But because second one does I do get the ID.

```
|ID_RESERVATION |  Arrival_time  |    Departure_time   |  ID_Parking_Space
|:------------- |:--------------:|: ------------------:|:----------------:|
|      6        |   2001-12-15   |    2002-12-15       |        4         |
|      16       |   2009-12-15   |    2010-12-15       |        4         |
```

In the full table there are more reservations and if one row doesn't meet the condition I need the select to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.ID_Parking_Space 
FROM Parking_Spaces p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Reservations r 
  WHERE r.ID_Parking_space = p.ID_Parking_Space
  AND (
    r.Arrival_time BETWEEN '2000-12-15' AND '2005-12-15' 
    OR 
    r.Departure_time BETWEEN '2000-12-15' AND '2005-12-15'
  )
);
```